# Android Board Game Implementation

Tags: android, button, tablelayout

So I'm creating a board game that uses a 9x9 board with different images for the edges/corners and the middle of the board. After doing a lot of research, people seem to recommend using a TableLayout with buttons or imageButtons for each individual space on the board.

What I am wondering is that in my game, the pieces can also be rotated by 45 degrees each turn. My original plan was to simply have the pieces as part of the imageButton, but I am not sure how I could rotate it. One option that I can think of would be to simply have an individual image for each 45deg rotation, but this seems extremely inefficient as it would require 8 images per piece.

Questions:

- Is a tablelayout the proper way to implement my board?
- Should I be using imagebuttons for each space on my board?
- What would be the best way to rotate my pieces? Should I use a canvas approach for the entire game?

Thank you and please let me know if anything isn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes table layout is a good aproach for this kind of layout IMO
- If you have to push on the image you can use ImageButtons, otherwise just use ImageView.
- You can rotate a drawable the following way.

  ```
  private void updateImageOrientation(final float rotationAngle) {

    // rotate compass to right orientation
    final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.actMyDrawableImage);
    // only if imageView in layout

    if (img != null) {
      final Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.act_my_drawable);
      // Getting width & height of the given image.
      final int w = bmp.getWidth();
      final int h = bmp.getHeight();
      // Setting post rotate to rotation angle
      final Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
      // Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Image rotation angle: " + rotationAngle);
      mtx.postRotate(rotationAngle, (float) (w / 2.0), (float) (h / 2.0));
      // Rotating Bitmap
      final Bitmap rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
      final BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), rotatedBMP);

      img.setImageDrawable(bmd);
    }

  }
  ```

**Edit 1**:

To use ImageButton just replace ImageView by ImageButton in he code above.

```
final ImageButton img = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.actMyDrawableImage);

img.setImageDrawable(drawable)
```

**Edit 2**

To show your pieces above your board you could use a FrameLayout for each of your cell. The background would be set:

- using an ImageView as below
- with a background flag on the FrameLayout (android:background)
- if you want one background for your board with a background flag on the parent TableLayout

You can make your pieces visible/invisible programatically:

```
img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

---

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/actMyDrawableButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible" >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/actMyDrawableButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible" >
    </ImageButton>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Is there a way to separate my game board tile from the actual pieces? Can you put an ImageView on top of an ImageButton? I need to be able to click on a piece and wanted to highlight the potential moves by switching the board image on the tiles that the piece can move to.

Comment: I don't understand your first question, sorry. No you don't have to put your ImageView on top of an ImageButton just use ImageButton instead of ImageView, I will update my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to explain my first question better. What I mean is that obviously my game board has tiles for the actual board and I also have individual pieces. The board tiles will always be there, and I'm trying to figure out a way to have my pieces sit on top of the tiles. For the rotation part, I only want the pieces, not the tiles, to rotate. This would require that the images be separate. I am wondering if there is a way to do this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I added an explanation to show or hide your pieces, hope it will help.